# SQL Server Agent - SSIS step - where configuration are stored

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for information at what table (of msdb I guess) are stored information of Parameters Value for SSIS step? I would like to script its update.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.command?

Comment: Looks like you're right. I had missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would like to know the answer on above question I had posted:

```
USE [msdb]
GO

  SELECT job_id,* 
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]
  WHERE [name] = 'MyJobName'


  UPDATE
  [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps]
  SET command = REPLACE(command, 'OldParameterValue','NewParamtereValue')
  WHERE job_id = 'unique_job_identity'
  and step_id = 1 --stepId if necessary, probably yes
```

Thank you @AlwaysLearning